# How to wrap a tag around second word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags

I have a 3-5 word sentence and I want to wrap the second word with `span`. For example if the sentence is:

`From the journal`, I want to convert it to `From <span>the</span> journal`

I am using method below:

```
public string cover2nd(string a)
{
    int pos = a.IndexOf(' ');
    return a.Substring(0, pos) + "<span class='color'>" + a.Substring(pos, pos + 1) +
           "</span>" + a.Substring(pos, a.Length - pos);
}
```

And it produces this:

`From <span>the</span> the journal`

As you can see, I couldn't make it start from the second space character. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last argument for Substring, you need go from the next space in the string, not the current one:

```
public string cover2nd(string a) {
        int pos = a.IndexOf(' ');
        int posNext = a.IndexOf(' ',pos+1);
        return a.Substring(0, pos) + "<span class='color'>" + 
               a.Substring(pos, posNext - pos) + "</span>" + a.Substring(posNext, a.Length - posNext );
    }
}
```

Comment: It became From<span class="color"> The </span> The Jou, didn't work

Comment: @Kuzgun: Just testing it - have changed the last line slightly.

Comment: For "From the journal" it works but I have another sentence "Clients love us" and it became "Clients<span class="color"> Love Us</span> Us " Why would it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try a different approach :

```
    String[] words = a.split(' ');
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //check your sentence is not empty
    sb.append(words[0]);
    sb.append("<span class='color'>");
    sb.append(words[1]);
    sb.append("</span>");
    for(int i = 2; i<words.lenght; i++)
       sb.append(words[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
string text = "From the world";
string[] array = text.Split(' ');
array[1] = "<span class='color'>" + array[1] + "</span>";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string cover2nd(string a)
{
    if(a == null)
        return a;

    String[] words = a.Split(' ');

    if(words.Length < 2)
        return a;

    words[1] = "<span class='color'>" + words[1] + "</span>";
    return String.Join(' ', words);

}
```

For more general usage, I would add a second parameter determining the index of the word around which a span is being wrapped.

```
public string coverItem(string a, int index)
{
    if(a == null)
        return a;

    String[] words = a.Split(' ');

    if(words.Length < index)
        return a;

    words[index-1] = "<span class='color'>" + words[index-1] + "</span>";
    return String.Join(' ', words);
}
```

usage :

```
string result = coverItem("From the journal", 2);
```